# Getting a pointer from inside of a function

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm creating a program that receives students name, grades, classrom, and print in the console who passed in the college.

I have a function:

```
void arrayPush(char (*insertionArray)[3][4][25], int studentsClass, char valueToInsert[25])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp((*insertionArray)[studentsClass][i], "0") == 0)
        {
            strcpy((*insertionArray)[studentsClass][i], valueToInsert);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("falso");
        }
    }
}
```

That receives a pointer as a parameter, but i'm calling it inside of a function that alsos receive a pointer as parameter:

```
void getStudentsSituation(char (*approvedList)[3][4][25], char (*reprovedList)[3][4][25],
                          int studentsAverage, char studentsName[25], int studentsClass)
{

    if (studentsAverage > 5)
    {
        arrayPush(approvedList, studentsClass, studentsName);
    }
    else if (studentsAverage < 5)
    {
        arrayPush(reprovedList, studentsClass, studentsName);
    }
}
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void getStudentsName(char (*studentsName)[25])
{
    char dummy;
    printf("Digite o nome do aluno: \n");
    scanf("%s", (*studentsName));
    scanf("%c", &dummy);
}

void getStudentsClass(int *studentsClass)
{

    char temporary[1];
    bool executeCode = true;

    while (executeCode == true)
    {
        printf("Digite a turma do aluno (A/B/C): ");
        scanf("%s", temporary);

        if (strcmp(temporary, "A") == 0)
        {
            *studentsClass = 0;
            executeCode = false;
        }

        if (strcmp(temporary, "B") == 0)
        {
            *studentsClass = 1;
            executeCode = false;
        }

        if (strcmp(temporary, "C") == 0)
        {
            *studentsClass = 2;
            executeCode = false;
        }
    }
}

void getStudentsGrade(int (*gradeArray)[4], int arr_length)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < arr_length; i++)
    {
        int temporary;
        printf("Digite a nota do %dº bimestre \n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &temporary);
        (*gradeArray)[i] = temporary;
    }
}

void getStudentsAverage(int (*gradeArray)[4], int *studentsAverage)
{
    int sumOfGrades = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        sumOfGrades += (*gradeArray)[i];
    }

    *studentsAverage = sumOfGrades / 4;
}

void arrayPush(char (*insertionArray)[3][4][25], int studentsClass, char valueToInsert[25])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp((*insertionArray)[studentsClass][i], "0") == 0)
        {
            strcpy((*insertionArray)[studentsClass][i], valueToInsert);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("falso");
        }
    }
}

void getStudentsSituation(char (*approvedList)[3][4][25], char (*reprovedList)[3][4][25], int studentsAverage, char studentsName[25], int studentsClass)
{

    if (studentsAverage > 5)
    {
        arrayPush(&approvedList, studentsClass, studentsName);
    }
    else if (studentsAverage < 5)
    {
        arrayPush(reprovedList, studentsClass, studentsName);
    }
}

int main()
{

    char approvedStudents[3][4][25] = {{"0", "0", "0", "0"}, {"0", "0", "0", "0"}, {"0", "0", "0", "0"}, {"0", "0", "0", "0"}};
    char reprovedStudents[3][4][25] = {{"0", "0", "0", "0"}, {"0", "0", "0", "0"}, {"0", "0", "0", "0"}, {"0", "0", "0", "0"}};
    char studentsName[25];
    int studentsGrades[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    int studentsClass;
    int studentsAverage;
    bool executeRoutine = 0;
    int studentsCounter = 0;

    getStudentsName(&studentsName);
    getStudentsClass(&studentsClass);
    getStudentsGrade(&studentsGrades, 4);
    getStudentsAverage(&studentsGrades, &studentsAverage);
    getStudentsSituation(&approvedStudents, &reprovedStudents, studentsAverage, studentsName, studentsClass);

    printf("%d", studentsAverage);

    return 0;
}
```

How can i pass the pointer of "approvedList" to the array push?

I want to pass the  approvedList pointer inside of the arrayPush

Comment: Maybe you could give more context.  The three-dimensional array looks really weird, and passing a pointer to it is even weirder; because of array-pointer decay, this is usually not necessary.  I'm not sure what the larger goal of this program is, but I feel like you may be on the wrong track toward reaching it.

Comment: You don't need `&` before arrays when passing them to functions. Just use the array name, and it will automatically decay to a pointer. Then you can remove the corresponding `*` in the function parameter lists.

Answer (score 0):

I just did the following said by Barmar:

I removed & before arrays when passing them to functions. I just used the array name and removed the corresponding * in the function parameter lists

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).